# ingress-nginx logs - lots of weird entries showing up

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, logz.io

I'm trying to get my logz.io set up and running and during that process I'm noticing that my ingress controller pod is spitting out a lot of logs. I don't know if its normal or not, but I see a TON of entries in the logs that look like this

```
[06/Sep/2019:21:27:14 +0000]TCP200004.999
[06/Sep/2019:21:27:17 +0000]TCP200005.000
[06/Sep/2019:21:27:19 +0000]TCP200005.001
[06/Sep/2019:21:27:22 +0000]TCP200004.999
[06/Sep/2019:21:27:24 +0000]TCP200005.001
[06/Sep/2019:21:27:27 +0000]TCP200005.000
.
.
.
```

Is this normal? Is my ingress configured wrong? I don't want to see thousands of these entries in my logz.io instance.

Comment: Does the problem still exist ?

Comment: Yes, problem still exists

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible I'm seeing this as well in our nginx-ingress-controller. Did you find out what was going on here?

Comment: no luck here, I'm able to drop these records from our logging solution so they don't get indexed anymore but they are still in the logs for the ingress controller

Comment: to answer if your ingress configured wrong, it would be great to see your ingress and ingress controller setup. Can you add this to your post?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, these logs records reflect *[TCP/UDP](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)* services configuration for upstream backends, when [*Nginx Ingress controller*](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) applies proxy stream for TCP/UDP connections from relevant `ConfigMap` by adding specific lua block to the nested  `Nginx` ingress controller Pod.

Find related discussion in [#3612](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3612) Github thread.